# smack stanzaFilter message with delivery receipts with received element

Tags: java, android-studio, smack-stack

smack stanzaFilter message with delivery receipts unable to  processStanza like  below format?

```
<message to="user1" id="jpkVg-831" from="user2"/><received xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts" id="msgdid" status="receipt"></received></message>
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @Bsquare can you tell me how do you type that in so fast? :D

Comment: Copy/paste from my own Stack Overflow Recipe book ^^